# how to search a data from firebase for android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[image: database image]

I want to search a condition ,if student studied at 'swe' department then i will show name and id for every student who are studied at swe department.

```
  DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user");
    databaseReference.orderByChild("department").equalTo("swe").addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String str = dataSnapshot.child("department").getValue(String.class);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,str,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: what is the issue here?

Comment: i want actual query for this condition .

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your current code fails to handle the fact that the result is a list. To solve this, loop over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()`:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user");
databaseReference.orderByChild("department").equalTo("swe").addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String str = dataSnapshot.child("department").getValue(String.class);

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,str,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```